# Adding specific file to rails test command causes an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

When I add a specific file or directory to the `rails test` command to run my controller tests, I get the following error:

```
/Users/foobar/name_of_app/test/application_controller_test_case.rb:1:in `<main>':uninitialized constant ActionDispatch (NameError)

class ApplicationControllerTestCase < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
```

Any idea what is causing the problem and how to fix it?

I'm running Rails 7.0.1 using Ruby 3.1.2 on macOS 13.3.1. My tests are Minitest.

When I run `bin/rails test` all of my tests run as expected.

When I run `bin/rails test test/models` or `bin/rails test test/system` the expected subset of tests run as expected.

But, when I run `bin/rails test test/controllers/day_controller_test.rb`, I get the "uninitialized constant" error above.  In fact, I get an error regardless of what I use as the third parameter (file name, directory name, file_name:line_number).  The error makes me think that some (or all) of Rails is not getting loaded when I specify only tests in the `controllers` directory. Or, perhaps, one of model and/or system tests causes the missing file to be loaded. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is that file missing `require "test_helper"` at the top?

Comment: Not exactly, but that was essentially the problem:  The 'require "test_helper"' was the _2nd_ require after require "application_controller_test_case". (Or you could say the problem was that application_controller_test_case is missing the 'require "test_helper"'.  In any case, problem solved.

Comment: For future readers who may encounter a similar problem but not quite understand the solution, `require "test_helper"` will load the application and all its classes, modules, libraries, etc. If you try to reference something that is loaded by `test_helper` *before* you load the application with `require "test_helper"` then you'll get this error. The problem is that you cannot reference something not yet loaded. The solution is to load it first with `require "test_helper"`.

Comment: You can answer your own question; it could be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that I had a missing `require 'test_helper'` statement. (@spickermann gave me the key clue.)

Here was the problem: My controller tests all inherit from a parent class I wrote: `ApplicationControllerTestCase`. This parent class inherits from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`; but, I did not `require 'test_helper'` from `ApplicationControllerTestCase`. Thus, when I went to run a controller test case individually, I got the `uninitialized constant` error.

I'm not exactly sure what order the "magic" happens in, but when I used `bin/rails test` to run all the tests, the necessary files got required before the test runner got to my controller tests.